# UITableView scrolling boundaries

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm populating data into an array which is then being inserted into a `UITableView`. However once the screen gets filled, new cells won't show up because they get appended to the bottom. Is there a way to have it auto-scroll to the bottom upon adding an item? Also, the scrolling works but it isn't ideal. For example, to get to the last item, the user has to scroll and hold down that gesture to make the item appear. IE. My `UITableView` can hold up to 17 items in its view. After 17 the user can then scroll, however they would not be able to select item 18 because they would have to hold down their scroll gesture. In order to select item 18 they'd have to add say another 10 items.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    // Usually the number of items in your array (the one that holds your list)
    return [_items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Where we configure the cell in each row

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"trap";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell... setting the text of our cell's label
    cell.textLabel.text = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `_items` and not `self.items`?  If you don't want to use the accessor, don't make it a property.

Comment: That array is the only object where I use the '_' and not "self." because I saw it done that way in a tutorial and didn't want to do anything different. Can you explain the difference please?

Comment: _items is fine. With self. you can do more customisation for you instance member variable, such as lazy instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to hold your drag gesture to show 18rd item, I think the problem is your tableView's height didn't set properly. Try to set height to your visible frame height.

Comment: I tried changing the height of the tableView in the storyboard editor but that didn't do anything. What would you suggest?

Comment: you can set height to 100 to see result. if result it's also height of fullscreen, it show you have set autoresizesSubviews property contains   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight, remove the flag and try again.

Comment: CGRect tvframe = [self.tbl frame];
    [self.tbl setFrame:CGRectMake(tvframe.origin.x,
                                   tvframe.origin.y,
                                   tvframe.size.width,
                                   tvframe.size.height + 100)];
I tried putting that in viewDidLoad but it did not do anything

Comment: self.tbl.frame = CGRectMake(tvframe.origin.x, tvframe.origin.y, tvframe.size.width, 100); self.tbl.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; set your tableView like these code.Then check the result, if ok, set 100 to proper height

Comment: No effect. I'm still unable to scroll down to the very bottom and view the last few items.

Comment: I still think tableView's height problem, I can't review your code, so you should check your code yourself to find out where height out of bounce.

Comment: Yeah it must be the height. I'll have to check it out tomorrow. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I fixed it with [self.tbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tbl.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-self.tbl.frame.origin.y)];

Answer (score 1):

When the tableView was loaded,you can set contentOffset manually because you can get the tableViewContentSize this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can not show the last item of the table.

> The problem most likely is that your tableview’s height is bigger than
>   you screen size. Or it can be auto layout issue. Try to make your tableview's height smaller.

Is there a way to have it auto-scroll to the bottom upon adding an item?

```
[self.items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trawl %d", count]];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.item.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES]
```

---

The following is my whole test Controller

```
@interface DPCalendarTestCreateEventViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DPCalendarTestOptionsCellDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation DPCalendarTestCreateEventViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.items = @[@"TEST", @"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST",@"TEST"].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonSelected)];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (void) doneButtonSelected{
    [self.items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trawl %d", self.items.count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Where we configure the cell in each row

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"trap";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell... setting the text of our cell's label
    cell.textLabel.text = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: [_items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trawl %d", count]];
    
    [self.tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_items.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    
    [self.tbl reloadData];                                                                 Resulted in a [UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).' error

Comment: reloadData and then scroll to bottom

Comment: For some reason that still doesn't do it.

Comment: Hi, Do you mean it doesn't scroll at all or it scrolls but still not to the bottom? I just tried in my project and it works fine.

Comment: I have copy and pasted my whole test controller file and check whether it works for you.

Comment: It turns out just putting the [self.tbl scrollToRow...] code after the reloadData did work, with some issues however. I would populate the list till item 17 (in which case the whole table would be filled). However, I would have to press my add button until item 23 for it to automatically scroll after each addiction. Then 18 would show, followed by 19 and so on. Another issue remains is that the last 4 items won't be able to be selected because the scroll doesn't "stay".